# Dbus/obex error with Bluetooth

Tags: 11.10, bluetooth

I paired my PC and mobile phone(SE C702).
Then I try to browse files on it.

But I get this error when I try to choose C702 on Nautilus:

> Could not display "obex://[00:24:EF:17:BB:45]/"
>
> Error: DBus error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message did not
>   receive a reply (timeout by message bus) Please select another viewer
>   and try again.

I tried find over the internet and found some ways to fix it:

- Use `blueman` (It doesn't help me)
- remove `gnome-vfs-obexftp` (But it's not installed)

What else can I do?

OS is Ubuntu 11.10
Desktop Manager is Unity

Answer (score 1):

11.10 live cd not worked but try Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in live cd. Do not installed any packeges and updates. This working with me.

I have same error (11.10 is live cd) and (10.04 is installed & upgraded) distro.

But when im a tested 10.04 in LIVE CD, no OBEX error and im get my images my phones witch are4 Nokia 2720a-2.